# Start Song at Specific Time Using Kivy SoundLoader Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, audio-player

I have been designing an android app which is a simple music player app I am successful in finding, playing and stopping the currently playing music but now where I am stuck is that as you must have seen in other

Music player apps in android like google play music when we slide the slider then the music starts from the position of the slider and now I don't want the slider I just want that we enter the minutes and seconds the song will be played from there

For example -: Suppose that a song is 3 minutes and 40 seconds long And when we enter any time (Suppose 2 min 00 seconds) Then the song will be played from the entered time (In this case the song will start from 2 min 00 sec) using the SongLoader kivy module

I am not able to figure out how to do this. So please can anyone help me

Answer (score 1):

Its quite simple,you can just seek the position you want,note that seeking is in seconds so you'll have to convert your minutes to seconds:

```
sound = SoundLoader.load('mytest.wav')
if sound:
    print("Sound found at %s" % sound.source)
    print("Sound is %.3f seconds" % sound.length)
    sound.play()

    # jump to 1min
    sound.seek(60)
```